# Magento 1 enable captcha on multiple website

Tags: magento-enterprise, enterprise-1.14, captcha

I'm running and old website **M1 EE 1.14**. The captcha under `System->Configuration->customers->customer configuration` can be enabled easily. However, when I switch the configuration scope to other websites, the captcha config is missing.

Does anyone know on how to enable captcha for each website individually?
[image]

Comment: it is working on the website configuration, I think you are switching to store not website.

Comment: @NikunjVadariya you are right, I was looking on the store view.

Comment: I have posted the same in the answer. Please upvote and accept it so it will help others too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a little mistake.

In **Current Configuration Scope:** You need to select website not store.

Because `captcha` is displayed base on the website.